# Have child in row (which is in a column)wrap

Tags: flutter

I'd like the last child in my row to wrap.I've tried to play around with wrap with no success. Changing the `Row` to a `Wrap` widget does make the last item wrap but the button widgets in the row act strangely. Probably something to do with with it being in a `Column`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      home: Scaffold(
        
        body: Column(
          
           crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
         
          children:[Text('Some widget 1'),
                   Text('Some widget 2'),
                   Text('Some widget 3'),
                   Text('Some widget 4'),
                    Row(children: [
                      Text('Some widget 5'),
                      Text('Some widget 6'),
                      TextButton(onPressed: null,child:Text("Private Policy")),
                       Text('Some widget 7'),
                      Text('Some widget 8'),
                       Text('Some widget 9'),
                      Text('Some widget 10'),
                      TextButton(onPressed: null,child:Text("Private Policy"))
                      
                      

                 ],)
                   ],
          
         
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Wrap` has that strange behavior, but you can overcome this with multiple `row` widgets. You need to assume how many widgets can occupy in row, and based on that increase the `row` widgets.

**Example:**

```
Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                Text('Some widget 1'),
                Text('Some widget 2'),
                Text('Some widget 3'),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                  Text('Some widget 6'),
                  Text('Some widget 7'),
                  TextButton(onPressed: null,child:Text("Private Policy")),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                  Text('Some widget 4'),
                  Text('Some widget 5'),
                  TextButton(onPressed: null,child:Text("Private Policy")),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean. I'm really only concerned with the column child that is a row.. And not sure what multiply row widgets will do..

Comment: Add number of widgets in row which can be shown horizontally, rest move to another row widget, like wise you can go ahead

Comment: not really understanding...an example would be great!

Comment: @flutter: I edited the answer, its little hacky but it should work

Answer (score -1):

Your row will overflow . half of the row child won't even show on the screen.
in order to show all your row child in row you need to use scrollView
Describe briefly what you want to achieve

Comment: I want the row to wrap to the next line

Comment: never thought giving suggestion could decrese my reputation points thanks